# Can I analyze a save game with world builder or another tool?

Tags: civilization-5

*A little background:* The game I'm currently playing (Pangea, Tiny, King, Marathon) with Egypt certainly looks ... interesting. I'm at turn 790 (AD 1770) and went for a cultural victory with 2 cities. France basically dominates the complete rest of the map (Rome still left though) and has 14 cities (6 puppets, 8 french), if far ahead in terms of military power and tech. (If it weren't for the crappy tactical AI, they'd have overrun me long ago.) Also France is at about the same culture level as I am, although my two cities are culture monsters with a lot wonders and all. (I guess this just goes to show quantity trumps quality in any Civilization game :-)

What I would like to do would be to somehow **analyze the save game**, i.e. open it up and check in on the details of the AI civilizations production/science/culture/city production etc. **to learn** for future games from the current state of this game. I vaguely remember I could do this in Civ4, but there doesn't seem anything in Civ5 to examine a *regular* save game? World builder only allow to open maps.

**TL;DR** Can I open a save game, complete with the current game state, in world builder or any other tool?

---

[Also asked on forums.civfanatics.com](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=462696)

Answer (score 1):

You can just load the saved game and then use [the excellent mod called IGE (In-Game Editor)](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=436912).

It lets you view and edit other civ's details, including their tech-tree, social policies, details of their cities, etc.